Replacing $x$ in Functional Equation
For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the function $f(x)$ satisfies $2f(x)+f(1-x)=x^2$. Then find $f(x)$.
Now the solution which my faculty provided was to replace $x$ with $1-x$ which will give us
$$2f(1-x)+f(x)=(1-x)^2$$ and then solve the equations to get $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{3}(x^2+2x-1)$
My question is why we can replace $x$ with $1-x$ because $x=1-x$ is valid only $x=1/2$? In general why does this replacement method works?
e.g. If a function $f(x)$ satisfies $f(x)+2f\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}\right)=x$ then is replacing $x$ with $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ valid because $x=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ has imaginary roots

You aren't replacing $x$ with $1-x$ because they are equal. You are replacing $x$ with $1-x$ because you are doing a substitution. This is clearer if you replace $x$ with $1-y$ instead. But then you'd have to rename $y$ to $x$ again to do the simultaneous equations.

In short, the $x$ in $f(x)$ is just a dummy variable, you can replace it with $f(t)$

"Here's a recipe for blueberry muffins"  "Can I substitute strawberries for blueberries"  "Yes, but strawberries are not equal to blueberries:  It's just that you can plug in any fruit in the placeholder indicated by 'bluberries'".  "Can I plug in $1-x$ where it says $x$?" "Yes, $x$ is a place holder so you can plug in anything, even a different expression that uses $x$ in a different context". "Does that mean $x =1-x$" "No, it just means you are plugging a different expression int a position that indicates a universal place holder."

Replace $x$ with $1-x$ is not the same that post the equation $x=1-x$ (it is just to take, for example $-4$ instead of $5$ and this for all the values of the variable $x$.

@fleablood That analogy works better as "Here's a recipe for fruit muffins. For example, to make blueberry muffins..." "Can I substitute strawberries for blueberries?" "Yes, that's another fruit which you can use in the recipe."

With the given functional equation $2f(x)+f(1-x)=x^2$ we can choose any value of $x$ and we should expect the equation to be true (since we're told that it holds for any real value of $x$).
If we set $x = 50$, we get that $2f(50) + f(49) = 50^2$.
If we set $x = 2t$, we get $2f(2t) + f(1-2t) = (2t)^2$.
If we set $x = 1 - y$, we get $2f(1 - y) + f(y) = (1 - y)^2$.
But, with the last one, it still holds for any value of $y$, since $y$ is just a placeholder variable. So we can go back and relabel $y$ to $x$, and we get the equation $2f(1 - x) + f(x) = (1 - x)^2$, and that should still hold true for any value of $x$, just as much as the original equation.
The one thing you need to be careful about is checking whether the substitution changes the domain over which the equation is expected to hold true - for example, if you're told that $f(x^2)$ has some behaviour for all $x$, then if you make the substitution $y = x^2$ you are restricted to $y \geq 0$.

you can just do it by taking value of x equal to y and 1-y .solve it and you will get a function in terms of y but usually in mathematics we plot a graph by taking input on x axis so we replace x with y in the end converting it into the function of x .
To speed up the process we directly say that we replace x by x and 1-x .

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
